# Python Attribute Error of 'can' BLFReader function

Tags: python, attributeerror

```
Python 3.9.4 (tags/v3.9.4:1f2e308, Apr  6 2021, 13:40:21) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import can
>>> filename = "test.blf"
>>> log = can.BLFReader(filename)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'can' has no attribute 'BLFReader'
>>>
```

I am trying to import CAN blf file with Python.

I used can module and BLFReader function, but it showed attributeerror as above.

my python version is 3.9.4.

How can i resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

BLFReader is in `python-can` and not in `can` package.

Uninstall `can` and install `python-can`:

```
pip3 uninstall can
pip3 install python-can
```

Then:

```
import can
can.BLFReader

# <class 'can.io.blf.BLFReader'>
```